# The driver.findelement don't find the tab element:

Tags: gwt, webdriver

i have this Problem with my test ..the

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/a[2]/em/span/span/span")).click();
```

don't find the element.

the eclipse show this message of error

> Cannot locate a node using
>   //html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/a[2]/em/span/span/span

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :** Post edited to reflect answer to actual problem. Original answer follows.

Long XPath expressions are fragile, and tests are prone to fail when relying on them : a completely unrelated change somewhere else in the document can mess everything up, and even if you're aware of the problem, the tests' code is just harder to maintain.

In this particular case, since the site is generated by GWT, it's even worse - there is little control over the actual HTML changes. A good solution when using GWT is to use the ensureDebugId method (see link in comments).

---

Are you sure that this XPath expression is correct ? Does other tests work with this driver ?

I'd recommend avoiding the use of long XPath expressions like that - wouldn't it be safer in the long term to start the expression at an id-specified div somewhere in the page rather than at the root of the DOM ?

Comment: for example the find until //html/body/div[2]/div" work  . its all component with gwt and don't work  by id, or dom or name...this parameter always change

Comment: @SasanG : For sites created with GWT I recommend using the DebugIds to make sure you have a way of controlling the IDs when you test. This will simplify a lot your XPath expressions and make your tests more resilient.
See : http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#ensureDebugId%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: If you use the .ensureDebugId("my-id") method on a UIObject, and have your gwt.xml properly set (see previous link) the Xpath of your item could probably be summarized to something like `//ul[@id='gwt-debug-my-id']/li[2]/a[2]/em/span/span/span` 
You can use the string you want as a debug id. It'll get prefixed (by "gwt-debug-" by default) and appear in the HTML.